# Rails, use a single delayed_job instance for all applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a server running several RoR applications. Some of them require delayed_job to handle picture resizing and other tasks. At the moment, I'm running delayed_job per each application... this results in a higher memory consumption.

Is it possible to **run a shared delayed_job instance on the server**, that will be used by applications?

Answer (score 1):

That would be suspicious. Delayed_job is supposed to run with the same codebase as the application requesting the jobs - it uses this fact for job serialization/deserialization which would be extremely difficult otherwise. In your case the jobs might be similar but at some point one of the applications is going to schedule a job that the delayed process simply won't understand.

Comment: The point is... if I have 20 applications requiring delayed_job, my server will face with memory issues. Any suggestion?

Comment: You could create a separate application which only handles the long running tasks (and does so via delayed_job). Other apps could communicate with it via a json API for example. I would also seriously consider if 20 apps on one server is a good idea - any of them experiencing lots of load might degrade the performance of all the others.

Comment: I know it's not ideal keeping together so many applications into the same server. But, due to company policies, I've no choice. Your idea is interesting, but leads me todevelop specific API to read and transfer data from related databases. I promise I will give it a thought. Thank you